# How to add minutes to time data?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Symbol  Date        Time            Bid Price   Bid Exchange    Bid Size    Ask Price   Ask Exchange    Ask Size
0    ABC  2014-03-03  09:30:00.033000   43.16           Z               1       43.69           P               3
1    ABC  2014-03-03  09:30:00.038000   43.17           P               3       43.69           P               3
2    ABC  2014-03-03  09:30:00.039000   43.17           P               4       43.69           P               3
3    ABC  2014-03-03  09:30:00.151000   43.3            P               6       43.69           P               3
4    ABC  2014-03-03  09:30:00.151000   43.3            P               6       43.42           P               4
```

I want to extract every minutes of the data and do some calculations. To do so, iteratively, I would add 1 minute to `start_time` and call it `end_time` then select data between `start_time` and `end_time` and do my analysis; my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date, time, timedelta

df = pd.read_csv('some_data_file.csv'))

#Converting strings to date and time
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time

start_date = datetime.date(2014, 3, 3)
end_date = datetime.date(2014, 3, 4)

day_i = df.loc[df['Date']==start_date]

start_time = day_i['Time'][0]

end_time = start_time + timedelta.time(minutes=1)

interval_i = day_i.loc[(day_i['Time'] >= start_time) & (day_i['Time'] <= end_time)]
```

`start_time` format is `datetime.time(9, 30, 0, 33000)`.

When I run:

```
end_time = start_time + timedelta.time(minutes=1)
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.timedelta' has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: Python `datetime.timedelta` doesn't have attribute `time`. You just call it as `timedelta(minutes=1)`

Comment: I tried then it gives this error: ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'```

Comment: you need to convert `day_i['Time']` to `timedelta` dtype by using `day_i['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(day_i['Time'])`

Comment: Still the same Erorr: ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'```.

Comment: ```type(start_time)``` is ```datetime.time```

Comment: did you do `day_i['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(day_i['Time'])` before assigning to `start_time` in `start_time = day_i['Time'][0]`? is there other place where `start_time` got assigned value?

Comment: Original data are string and I convert them to date and time. I updated the code above to show earlier steps.

Comment: You should make just one column of datetime only, and resample from that column.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the type for **start_time** and **end_time**  are of **type time** and are NOT of **type datetime**.  Convert to type time if needed.

```
type(start_time)
```

Example:
`start_time = (9, 30, 0, 0)
 end_time = start_time + timedelta(seconds=60)`

You should get: `end_time = (9, 30, 1, 0)`

You can also try **pandas between_time()**
`myrows = df['Time'].between_time(start_time, end_time)`

> DataFrame.between_time(start_time, end_time, include_start=True, include_end=True)[source]
>   Select values between particular times of the day (e.g., 9:00-9:30 AM).